# Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CityService -> Http]: No provider for Http

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine

I have this service that return all City from ws.

```
@Injectable()
export class CityService {
  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router,
  private auth: AuthService) { }

  public getAllCity(): Observable<City[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.getAllCity), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(city => {
            return new City(city);
          });
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Now, I tried this code to test my service. In this post I want to know, How to test this service `CityService`

```
describe('Service: City', () => {
    let component: CityService;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CityService>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [],
            providers: [CityService] 
        })
        fixture = TestBed.get(CityService);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
   it('#getAllCity should return real value', () => {
     expect(component.getAllCity()).toBe('real value');
  });
});
```

I tried this code, but show me error:

> Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CityService -> Http]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CityService -> Http]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!

How to test / how to show my city in `ng test`?

This is my first attempt, can you suggest me any example, or tutorial like my code?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Yes of course @gentlyawesome

Answer (score 3):

`CityService` depends on 3 services, namely `Http`, `Router` and `AuthService`. You need to inject them into the test.

```
describe('Service: City', () => {
    let service: CityService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [],
            providers: [CityService, AuthService],  // all all services upon which AuthService depends
            imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule], 
        });
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        service = TestBed.get(CityService);
    });

    it('#getAllCity should return real value', () => {
        expect(service.getAllCity()).toBe('real value');
    });
});
```

https://angular.io/guide/testing - this is a must-read for unit testing Angular.
https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests - part related to testing services.
https://angular.io/guide/http#setup-1 - related to testing calls made with Http service.

Comment: I modify `providers: [CityService,Http, AuthService, ConnectionBackend           ], imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpModule]` and now show this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of null

Comment: That's another problem, unrelated to this question.

Comment: You shouldn't inject the real http client into a test context; unit tests shipment make network calls, and I don't think it will work anyway.

Comment: Thanks for comment @jonrsharpe, I updated the answer.

Comment: `Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CityService -> Http]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CityService -> Http]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Http!`